# How to change meta description dynamically on product details page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to change **meta description** and **title** dynamically on product details page.

Meta description should be **catagory Name  + product name**.

Comment: meta information is not something that is visible for the user

Comment: <meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="description" content="test abc, xyz,jghf,hjfhf"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="abc"/>
<meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>

Comment: @PawanArya, You can manage the name from the admin but for category you need to do some customization.
check below configuration :
`admin->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog->Product Fields Auto-Generation->Mask for Meta Description`

Comment: @Amit Naraniwal , i want to do from code with out using backpanel